Snowflake - break inner loop inside stored procedure
I have two for loops like this inside a task:
DECLARE
    response_string STRING;
    result BOOLEAN;
    stream_result resultset;
    query_result resultset;
    c1 CURSOR FOR stream_result;
    c2 CURSOR FOR query_result;
BEGIN
    IF (SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_1') = true) THEN stream_result := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_1 ORDER BY process_date);
    ELSEIF (SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('db.schema.stream_2') = true) THEN
        stream_result := (SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_2 ORDER BY process_date);
    END IF;

    FOR row_variable IN c1 DO
        query_result := (SELECT stg.flag FROM db.schema.status_loads stg WHERE row_variable.process_date = stg.process_date);
        FOR row_variable_2 IN c2 DO
            IF (row_variable_2.flag = 1) THEN
                result := true;
            ELSE    
                result := false;
                BREAK INNER;
            END IF;
        END FOR;
        IF (:result = true) THEN
            response_string := (call sp_1(row_variable.process_date));
            RETURN(:response_string);
        ELSE 
            RETURN(row_variable.process_date);
        END IF;
    END FOR;

I'm getting error when this task is triggered, error:

SQL compilation error: error line 29 at position 16
Label 'INNER' not found

I'd tried 'BREAK inner_loop;' also but getting same error.
How can I break the inner for loop only when result is equal to false?

You haven’t named your loops so Snowflake doesn’t know what your label “INNER” refers to. This is documented with an example here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/loops#specifying-where-execution-should-continue-after-termination

Hi, can this be achieved with for loops?

And other question, if i only put a BREAK; not BREAK inner or something else its ok, but gives me this error: Stored procedure execution error: uninitialized resultSet 'stream_result'. I've tried to set another VARCHAR called select_statement variable and assigned to it a string with the 'SELECT process_date FROM db.schema.stream_2 ORDER BY process_date' and then: stream_result := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :select_statement); but gives me the same error
